# Transaction to a specific fragment if we receive a push notification while app is running

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification

Is it possible not launch new activity if we receive a push notification while the app is running?
My activity works with fragments and I want to do transition to a determinate fragment when the notification is received. My activity have data that I need to show the fragments. The problem is that when I receive the push notification while the app is running the method onDestroy is called and here I clear the data and then the app crash because the data are null. How can I do to not create new activity when the app receive a push notification while is running? In case the app is running I want that if you click the notification do a transition fragment, not create again the activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that you mean "notification" to be a "message", but not `android.app.Notification` class.

And second, I don't think it's a best practise to raise new GUI when receiving a message, which would interrupt the user interaction. For details, please refer to: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/index.html and http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html.

At last, if you really wanna do what you stated in your thread, I wonder why the data used to generate the show-data fragment is held in the activity. Try holding the data in an `android.app.IntentService` object, and then generate transfer the data to new activity, and then use `android.app.Fragment.setArguments` method to transfer the data from activity to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible and I do such a thing in one of my apps. First, you need to declare your activity as `android:launchMode="singleTop"`,

Then, when you build you must configure your pending intent not to fire a new instance of your activity:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR ACTION HERE");  
intent.setClassName(this, MainActivity.class.getName());

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

mNotificationManager.notify(idNotificacion,notification);
```

Now all you have to do is to override your `onNewIntent` inside your `Activity` and do whatever you want with your `fragment`:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
        MiLog.i(getApplicationContext(),"IntentShit","new intent received");
        MiLog.i(getApplicationContext(),"IntentShit","Action: "+intent.getAction());

        if(intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals("YOUR ACTION HERE"){
   //DO your stuff here
}
}
```

You should also take a look at this page for more info:
http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code will help you. This which you need is PendingIntent, it make transaction to desired activity.

```
    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */

    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String title,
            String message) {

        //get the default notification sound URI
        Uri uriNotificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        //make intent to the application. if the application is opened just maximize it.
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context, 'your desired activity');
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                homeIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("eCommCongress")
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 1500, 1500)
                        .setSound(uriNotificationSound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.

        mNotificationManager.notify(counter, mBuilder.build());

        counter++;
}
```